# What Current Motherboard Form Factors Will Fit An LPX Case?

Tags: motherboard, case

I have an all in one PC from the mid-90s (Compaq Presario 3020 - See below).
Based on the riser and from what I can measure (9" x 13"), it looks like an LPX form factor motherboard/case.

I want to bring it back to life and just do very simple stuff with it, e.g. file server or a Classic Arcade Game emulator.

Therefore, it doesn't have to be too powerful or need much cooling.

Which motherboard form-factors will be able to fit and line up the I/O ports without looking *too* out of place?

Bonus points if you can suggest an actual motherboard + CPU that isn't too expensive (new or used is fine)!

[image: Compaq Presario 3020 Side View]

[image: Compaq Presario 3020 Rear View Open]

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be viable options:

- [Mini-ITX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-ITX) is 6.7" x 6.7"
- [Micro ATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX) is 9.6" x 9.6", however, some are smaller e.g. [this MSI H97-G43](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K33PLZS) is 11.6" x 8.7"
- [FlexATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexATX) is 9" x 7.5" but is harder to come by

These will fit based on their sizes although I don't know whether the holes or I/O ports will line up.

Comment: "holes or I/O ports will line up" is the tricky part IMO. Also, power looks like it'll be a pain. That's a wierd PSU. How's the monitor connected? Feels almost like gutting a newer/old laptop or sticking a nuc class machine feels like a good idea.

Comment: The monitor is connected via that orange ribbon to a PCI graphics card that connects to the motherboard via the riser card. I haven't checked power yet but I want to bring it back to life for nostalgia reasons :)

Comment: I mean, it is a non standard power supply so you can't just drop a new/modern one in.